# How do I redirect output to a variable file name in a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

How do I redirect output to a variable file name in a for loop?

This doesn't work:

```
for ((j=501; j <=550; j++)); do 
curl -x http://us-wa.proxymesh.com:31280 "https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg=D${j}&searchCode=CALL%2B&searchType=1&limitTo=none&fromYear=&toYear=&limitTo=LOCA%3Dall&limitTo=PLAC%3Dall&limitTo=TYPE%3Dall&limitTo=LANG%3Dall&recCount=1000" >trial_$j_out.html 2> trial_$j_error.txt;
done
```

I keep on having trial_.html and trial_.txt written.

Comment: Because you have no `j_out` or `j_error` variable defined. Just replace `trial_$j_out.html` and `trial_$j_error.txt` with `trial_${j}_out.html` and `trial_${j}_error.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, `_` is a valid character in a variable name.  The shell will interpret `trial_$j_out.html` and `trial_$j_error.txt` as consisting of text surrounding the variables `$j_out` and `$j_error`.

Use `${j}` instead, just like you (needlessly) did in the actual URL:

```
for (( j=501; j<=550; j++ )); do 
    curl -x http://us-wa.proxymesh.com:31280 \
        "https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg=D$j&searchCode=CALL%2B&searchType=1&limitTo=none&fromYear=&toYear=&limitTo=LOCA%3Dall&limitTo=PLAC%3Dall&limitTo=TYPE%3Dall&limitTo=LANG%3Dall&recCount=1000" \
        >"trial_${j}_out.html" 2>"trial_${j}_error.txt"
done
```

This will properly delimit the name of the variable from the following `_`.  The `$j` in the URL does not need curly braces as the character `&` is not valid as part of a variable name.